# problem with keyring prompt

Tags: password

Keyring and user accounts reject my login password. I can use this password when logging in at start up and sudo accepts it ok when using terminal. However when i use the same password to unlock user accounts or change keyring password. It says the password is incorrect. Just want to get rid of the keyring as it now needs 5 clicks on cancel on popup to close it .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To remove just gnome-keyring package itself execute on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-keyring
```

To remove the gnome-keyring package and any other dependant package which are no longer needed from Ubuntu Xenial.

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gnome-keyring
```

If you also want to delete configuration and/or data files of gnome-keyring from Ubuntu Xenial then this will work:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-keyring
```

To delete configuration and/or data files of gnome-keyring and it's dependencies from Ubuntu Xenial then execute:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove gnome-keyring
```

Source:

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/gnome-keyring?action=remove